# Customizing an image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these 2 dividers:

HTML:

```
<div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>

<div id="second">
<img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
#first
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;
}
#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

#second
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;
}
#second img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

---

I'm looking to put them both in a slider so i can manipulate between them, divider by divider.
I got this below code and tried to manipulate but couldn't make it work except image by image from one divider "first".
Any help please!

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p onclick="left()">
                <</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="first" style="display:inline-block;">
                <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <img id="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p onclick="right()">></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
html {
    font-size: 50px;
}
#first {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 150px;
    width: 740px;
}
img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

script:

```
window.left = function () {
    $('img:first').before($('img:last').get(0).outerHTML);
    $('img:last').remove();
}
window.right = function () {
    $('img:last').before($('img:first').get(0).outerHTML);
    $('img:first').remove();
}

$('img:even').css('opacity','.6');  // make even images lighter

window.left = function () {
    $('img:first').before($('img:last').get(0).outerHTML);  // copy the last picture before the first one.
    $('img:last').remove();  // remove the last picture from the end of the stack.
}
window.right = function () {
    $('img:last').before($('img:first').get(0).outerHTML);  // copy the first picture after the last one.
    $('img:first').remove();  // remove the first picture from the beginning of the stack
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/1vq62s1d/

It needs to slide and be in this shape:
[image]

It needs to be in this form: 2 parallel horizontal lines with 5 images on each line.

I know it's too much to ask but i've been working on it for 3 days for now and can't get anywhere since i'm new in jquery. I would appreciate any help please!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use tables for non-tabular content. Also, you should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of < and > inside HTML tags.

I used your JSFIDDLE code to come up with the following solution, but you will get two rows of images only on wide screens. On narrow devices the images will wrap.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
    <div onclick="left()" class="colMargin">&lt;</div>
    <div style="width:90%;float:left;max-width:560px;">
        <img id="image1" title="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image2" title="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image3" title="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image4" title="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image5" title="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image6" title="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image7" title="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image8" title="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image9" title="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        <img id="image10" title="image10" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div onclick="right()" class="colMargin">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('img:even').css('opacity', '.6'); // make even images lighter

window.left = function () {
    $('img:first').before($('img:last').get(0).outerHTML); // copy the last picture before the first one.
    $('img:last').remove(); // remove the last picture from the end of the stack.
}
window.right = function () {
    $('img:last').after($('img:first').get(0).outerHTML); // copy the first picture after the last one.
    $('img:first').remove(); // remove the first picture from the beginning of the stack
}
```

CSS

```
html {
    font-size: 50px;
}
img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#first {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}
#first img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.colMargin{
    width:5%;
    float:left;
    height:220px;
}
```

See it here JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sjx6qwt6/5/

I removed the last two duplicate functions from the Javascript in your JSFIDDLE, and changed `$('img:last').before` to `$('img:last').after` in the `window.right` function.

**NOTE:** I added title attributes to the images to test that the scrolling works correctly.